# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError suddenly on code that used to work - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

Running the code below was working fine, then I made a new class which would run through Prestart and deleted it shortly after (and all traces of it).

However something has gone wrong and I keep getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when trying to run the code again.
This error shown on the line calling `new Prestart();` (code is at the bottom)

This is strange since the Prestart.java is in the same location:
[image]

```
package plugins.Zyzyx.theproj;

import icy.plugin.abstract_.PluginActionable;

public class MultiFretIcy extends PluginActionable {

    Prestart PS;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        PS = new Prestart(); //Error targets this line
        PS.run();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what could have gone wrong, everything seems to be in order.
Any suggestions on things I should check/correct? I'm using Eclipse.

**UPDATE:**
Trying clean I'm getting a new error now. To clarify my program is exported as a .jar which is loaded and ran by another program (there's no fault with this program as it runs other .jar files fine).

The new error:

> JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/Startup.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPPointsPair.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPSimilarityRegistrationAnalytic.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPROI2D2.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/MonitorObject.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/TestRun.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/TheProj.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/Threadingbackup.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/TransfoMaker.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPPPPoint3D.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPApplyTransformation.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPSimilarityTransformation3D.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/MM.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/MultiFretIcy.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPStack3DVTKTransformer.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/InterruptHandler.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/Threading.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/EzVarIntRoi.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/ClemPoints.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/fPos.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPSimilarityTransformation2D.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/MyWaitNotify.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/Splitter.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/Graphs.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/Prestart.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPTargetRegistrationErrorMap.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/plugins/Zyzyx/theproj/CPImageTransformer.java'
>
> Class files on classpath not found or not accessible for:
>   'MultiFretIcy/src/poi/CreateWorkBook.java'
>
> Could not read JAR file 'Prestart.java'. Reason: zip END header not
>   found
>
> ```
> zip END header not found
>
> zip END header not found
> ```

Comment: Have you already tried to *clean* your project?

Comment: Check the build path for any missing jar file

Comment: @PM77-1 Tried it just now, I'm getting a new error now. I will update the Question with the results

Comment: @Dev The build path contains all jar file references, this doesn't seem to be the issue